# Which files affect the path in bash on Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, bash, shell, command-line, terminal

I'm debugging a `bash` program, and I'm a bit confused about how the `PATH` is set in Mac OS X. For example, I have a relatively fresh laptop which has `Server.app` and `homebrew` installed but not much else. When I delete my `~/.bashrc` and `~/.bash_profile` files, and do `echo $PATH`, I get:

```
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Applications/Server.app/Contents/ServerRoot/usr/bin:/Applications/Server.app/Contents/ServerRoot/usr/sbin
```

How is my `PATH`being modified?

Comment: take a look at settings of your terminal emulator application

Comment: Maybe I should have specified, I'm actually using `ssh` to access this laptop's command line (I work from a different laptop.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what you are looking for is `path_helper`

from `man path_helper`

```
  The path_helper utility reads the contents of the files in the directo-
     ries /etc/paths.d and /etc/manpaths.d and appends their contents to the
     PATH and MANPATH environment variables respectively.  (The MANPATH envi-
     ronment variable will not be modified unless it is already set in the
     environment.)

     Files in these directories should contain one path element per line.

     Prior to reading these directories, default PATH and MANPATH values are
     obtained from the files /etc/paths and /etc/manpaths respectively.
```

if you look it is being called in /etc/profile

```
[~] cat /etc/profile
# System-wide .profile for sh(1)

if [ -x /usr/libexec/path_helper ]; then
    eval `/usr/libexec/path_helper -s`
fi

if [ "${BASH-no}" != "no" ]; then
    [ -r /etc/bashrc ] && . /etc/bashrc
fi
```

Comment: Note that on OS X (and others) there is an `/etc/bashrc` as well.  That doesn't set `PATH`, but it is where some terminal variables are set (like `PS1`).